# Agent-Modelling System on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, dynamic, netlogo

I am starting on a project to simulate agents on the google app engine. I plan to have a control panel like so:
[image: Control Panel]
<sub>(source: [complexityworkshop.com](http://complexityworkshop.com/cw/tutorial/NetLogoAll.gif))</sub>

**My question is during simulation, the server has to process tasks again and again and display them onto the graph. What is the best possible way?**

Obviously I want to avoid refreshing the page again and again. I am intermediate in HTML, I am so-so in web applications. So a pointer in the right direction is needed.

Thanks!
Digvijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at either the appengine channel API, or the XMPP support.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/

Choice of approach (channel vs xmpp)  could depend a lot on how you build you UI.

Comment: The Chanel API seems to be it. "The Channel API creates a persistent connection between your application and Google servers, allowing your application to send messages to JavaScript clients in real time without the use of polling"
However, could you elaborate on how the UI would have to be built differently?

Comment: No, what I meant was the choice of xmpp vs channel should consider the type of UI you will build. If your UI was to be a standalone App (for instance using Kivy, or Qt) then it would probably easier to use XMPP rather than the channel api.  The channel api is much easier for browser based UI's as the channel client is javascript.